# How to Decode JSON Object File in PHP

Tags: java, android, json, android-studio, android-volley

I used JSON Request to send some parameters now I want to convert my json data by using json_decode but it does not allowing me to do so.

```
private void makeJsonObjReq() {
        Map<Object, Object> postParam = new HashMap<>();
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        final String URL = "https://www.facilesol.com/api/test.php";
        ArrayList<Map> myArray = new ArrayList<>();
        Cursor data2 = dbHelper.getAllData();
        if (data2.getCount() == 0) 
        {
             Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Your cart is empty", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } 
        else if (data2.moveToFirst()) {
            while (!data2.isAfterLast()) {
                Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<>();
                int pId = data2.getInt(1);
                String quantity = data2.getString(3);
                String price = data2.getString(4);
                String priceID = data2.getString(6);
                String toppingID = data2.getString(7);
                map1.put("product_id", String.valueOf(pId));
                map1.put("price_id", String.valueOf(priceID));
                map1.put("topping_id", String.valueOf(toppingID));
                map1.put("quantity", quantity);
                map1.put("sale_price", String.valueOf(price));
                myArray.add(map1);
                data2.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        postParam.put("branch_db",branchDb);
        postParam.put("line_items", myArray);

        Log.d(TAG, myArray.toString());

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                URL, new JSONObject(postParam),
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
//                        Toast.makeText(CheckOut.this, String.valueOf(response), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        try {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                //Toast.makeText(CheckOut.this, "Please fill correct information and check your internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                100000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        jsonObjReq.setTag(TAG);
        // Adding request to request queue
        queue.add(jsonObjReq);
    }

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

API File

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


<?php
    include(DBConn.php);
        $DBName = $_GET["branch_db"];

    $JsonFile = $_GET["line_items"];
    $arr = json_decode($JsonFile, true);

    $Query = "SELECT MAX(cartid) As MaxOrderID FROM  poscustomershoppingdata".
                " WHERE cartid LIKE '".date("Ymd")."%'";
            $rstOdr = mysql_db_query($DBName,$Query);
            if (mysql_num_rows($rstOdr) > 0)
            {
                $objOdr = mysql_fetch_object($rstOdr);
                if($objOdr->MaxOrderID == NULL)
                {
                    $OrderID = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    $OrderID = substr($objOdr->MaxOrderID,9,11);
                }
            }
            $OrderID = $OrderID + 1;
            $CartID = date("Ymd")."-".str_pad($OrderID, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
            //echo $CartID ."    ";
            $CartDate = date("Y-m-d h:i:s");

    $SqlCommand = "SELECT MAX(transid) FROM poscustomershopping";
    $Result = mysql_db_query($DBName,$SqlCommand);
    $MaxID = mysql_fetch_array($Result);
    $TransactionID = $MaxID['0'];
    $TransactionID = $TransactionID + 1;

    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) 
    {
         $Query = "INSERT INTO poscustomershopping".
                    " (cartid, transid, productid, priceid, toppingid, cartdate, quantity, saleprice) ".
                    " VALUES ($CartID, $TransactionID, '".($value["product_id"])."', '".($value["price_id"])."', '".($value["topping_id"])."', NOW(), '".($value["quantity"])."', '".($value["sale_price"])."')";
                    //echo $Query; die;
         mysql_db_query($DBName,$Query);
    }
        //echo $Data; die;

?>
```

In Android Debugger everything is fine as shown in image[Debugger Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEf6s.png) but when I tried to decode_json file received via parameter I can't be able to insert data in mySQL although there is no error at all. Please brief me where is the issue and how can identify it for solution purposes.

Comment: So are you asking about the PHP code?  Because the tags for this question are nearly all Java and Android related.  If the question is about PHP, use `php` tags.  And get rid of the irrelevant Java and Android tags!

Comment: For some instant it is PHP question but only android expert can answer this because this is APIs work related that are integrated with Android

Comment: Your question is *"How to Decode JSON Object File **in PHP**"*.   That is a PHP question.  And ... *"... when I tried to decode_json file received via parameter I can't be able to insert data in mySQL although there is no error at all."* ... is a PHP problem.  Now, perhaps that's not what you *meant*.  But it is not what you meant, you need to fix the question to make it clear what you are actually asking here.

Comment: And maybe you can do yourself a favor by debugging the PHP and looking at the JSON that it is receiving.